# Error while connecting Azure Data Studio working with Docker in a container with SQL Server

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, azure, asp.net-core

I'm having a issue with the connection at SQL Server via Azure Data Studio.
I'm trying to do the connection on MacBook Air M1 - Ventura 13.0.1
I saw common asks here, but I didn't get to the solution. Any kind of help will be welcome.

The error that I'm getting is

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 35 - An internal exception was caught)
> ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate was rejected by the provided RemoteCertificateValidationCallback.
> at System.Net.Security.SslStream.SendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, ExceptionDispatchInfo exception)
> at System.Net.Security.SslStream.CompleteHandshake(SslAuthenticationOptions sslAuthenticationOptions)
> at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Security.SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslClientAuthenticationOptions)
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.SNITCPHandle.EnableSsl(UInt32 options)
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.EnableSsl(UInt32 info, SqlConnectionEncryptOption encrypt, Boolean integratedSecurity) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ConsumePreLoginHandshake(SqlConnectionEncryptOption encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean& marsCapable, Boolean& fedAuthRequired, Boolean tlsFirst) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Boolean withFailover) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, String accessToken, DbConnectionPool pool) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.WaitForPendingOpen() --- End of stack trace from previous location --- at Dapper.SqlMapper.QueryAsync[T](IDbConnection cnn, Type effectiveType, CommandDefinition command) in /_/Dapper/SqlMapper.Async.cs:line 417 at Application.Repository.EmployeeRepository.GetAllEmployeesAsync() in /Users/ddxkalin/Dev/ProdSys/Application/Repository/EmployeeRepository.cs:line 21 at API.Controllers.EmployeesController.GetAllEmployeesAsync() in /Users/ddxkalin/Dev/ProdSys/API/Controllers/EmployeesController.cs:line 18 at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(ActionContext actionContext, IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
> at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> ClientConnectionId:da9520c9-1356-49ad-add6-0ed52ee9937b
> Error Number:-2146893019,State:0,Class:20

In appsettings.json the connectionString is

```
    "SqlConnection": "server=localhost;database=ProdSysDB;User Id=sa;Password=Admin123@;Integrated Security=true;"
```

This are the connection details in the Azure Data Studio for the Connection
[image: This are the connection details in the Azure Data Studio for the Connection]

Comment: Aside... choose one authentication method and stick with it. `Integrated Security=true;` means to use the Windows/Active Directory/Kerberos authentication token of the current process. `User Id=...;Password=...;` means to use SQL Login credentials.

Comment: Given the error message is `AuthenticationException: The remote certificate was rejected by the provided RemoteCertificateValidationCallback` did you notice that you have `Trust Server Certificate: true` selected in your ADS connection window? Do you think the two might be related? Have you tried adding `Trust Server Certificate=true;` to your connection string? Ref: [SqlConnectionStringBuilder.TrustServerCertificate Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.trustservercertificate).

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Yes the issue was with the Integrated Security, when I removed it and added the TrustServerCetificate=true everything is working fine! Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: @AlwaysLearning as your comment resolved the issue, please post it as answer to help other community members.

Answer (score 0):

As AlwaysLearning suggested in comments posting it as answer to help other community members.

The instance name in the connection string and the anticipated name from the instance are incompatible, which may be the cause of the `The remote certificate was rejected by the provided RemoteCertificateValidationCallback`.

Use `Trust Server Certificate` as `true`, when you use `TrustServerCertificate=true` (or its equivalent) in the connection string, the connection process skips the trust chain validation.

- Because `integrated security` is more a Windows feature, you must have windows authentication.
- *Integrated Security* is the type of user authentication. True corresponds to “**Windows Authentication**”, and False corresponds to “**SQL Server Authentication**”;